# JOOQ: Type class org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl is not supported in dialect DEFAULT

Tags: java, oracle, jooq

My question about writing query in jooq dsl.

I have some list of client attributes stored in an Oracle database.

Table structure is following:

- `CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE_DICT` (ID, CODE, DEFAULT_VALUE) - list of all possible attributes
- `CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE` (ATTRIBUTE_ID, CLIENT_ID, VALUE) - attributes values for different clients

I'm trying to select values of all existing attributes (in dict) for given client:

If exist row in CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE with given clientId than attribute value =  `CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE.VALUE` else `CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE_DICT.DEFAULT_VALUE`

My query in SQL (works fine):

```
SELECT d.code,
  NVL 
 (
  (
   SELECT value
   FROM CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE a
   WHERE a.ATTRIBUTE_ID = d.id
   AND a.CLIENT_ID      = 1 
  ),
  ( 
   SELECT DEFAULT_VALUE 
   FROM CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE_DICT dd 
   WHERE dd.id=d.id
  ) 
 ) value
FROM CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE_DICT d;
```

My query in Jooq dsl:

```
ClientAttributeDictTable dict = CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE_DICT.as("d");
Map<String, String> attributes = 
dsl.select(
 dict.CODE,
 DSL.nvl(
        dsl.select(CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE.VALUE)
           .from(CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE)
           .where(
                  CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE.ATTRIBUTE_ID.eq(dict.ID),
                  CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE.CLIENT_ID.eq(clientId)
                 ),

        dsl.select(CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE_DICT.DEFAULT_VALUE)
           .from(CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE_DICT)
           .where(CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE_DICT.ID.eq(dict.ID))
       ).as("value")
    ).from(dict)
     .fetchMap(String.class, String.class);
```

When jooq query runs it fails with error message:

> Caused by: Type class org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl is not supported in dialect DEFAULT
>
> > at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.getDataType(DefaultDataType.java:757) ~[na:na]
> >     at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.getDataType(DefaultDataType.java:704) ~[na:na]
> >     at org.jooq.impl.DSL.getDataType(DSL.java:14378) ~[na:na]
> >     at org.jooq.impl.DSL.val(DSL.java:12766) ~[na:na]
> >     at org.jooq.impl.Utils.field(Utils.java:802) ~[na:na]
> >     at org.jooq.impl.DSL.nvl(DSL.java:8403) ~[na:na]

What am I doing wrong?

**UPD**
JOOQ version **3.7.2**

Comment: Can you paste the full stack trace (or at least the relevant parts), to see where that exception is thrown? Also: What jOOQ version are you using?

Comment: Hi, Lukas!
I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is two-fold.

1. Your API usage is currently not supported (jOOQ currently doesn't accept `Select` types in the `nvl()` function). Write this instead:

   ```
   DSL.nvl(
       DSL.field(dsl.select(CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE.VALUE)
   //  ^^^^^^^^^ explicitly wrap the Select in a Field 
          .from(CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE)
          .where(
                 CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE.ATTRIBUTE_ID.eq(dict.ID),
                 CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE.CLIENT_ID.eq(clientId))),

       DSL.field(dsl.select(CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE_DICT.DEFAULT_VALUE)
   //  ^^^^^^^^^ explicitly wrap the Select in a Field
          .from(CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE_DICT)
          .where(CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE_DICT.ID.eq(dict.ID)))
   ).as("value")
   ```
2. jOOQ (or rather, the Java compiler) cannot detect this API misusage, because the `nvl()` API is overloaded in a way that always compiles. This is issue https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5340 and will be fixed in a future version (probably jOOQ 3.9)

Answer (score 0):

I found workaround.

First I rewrited SQL query:

```
SELECT D.CODE, NVL(S.VALUE, D.DEFAULT_VALUE) ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
FROM CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE_DICT D
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT DD.ID,
    A.VALUE
  FROM CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE_DICT DD
  JOIN CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE A
  ON A.ATTRIBUTE_ID = DD.ID
  WHERE A.CLIENT_ID = 1
  ) S ON S.ID       = D.ID;
```

Than I express my query in JOOQ dsl:

```
String ID_FIELD_NAME    = "ID";
String VALUE_FIELD_NAME = "VALUE"

ClientAttributeDictTable DICT_ATTRIBUTES = CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE_DICT.as("D");
Table<Record2<Long, String>> EXISTING_ATTRIBUTES =
    dsl.select(CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE_DICT.ID, CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE.VALUE)
       .from(CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE_DICT)
       .join(CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE)
       .on(CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE.ATTRIBUTE_ID.eq(CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE_DICT.ID))
       .where(CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE.CLIENT_ID.eq(clientId))
       .asTable("S", ID_FIELD_NAME, VALUE_FIELD_NAME);

Field<String> ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_FIELD = 
    nvl(
        EXISTING_ATTRIBUTES.field(VALUE_FIELD_NAME, String.class),
        DICT_ATTRIBUTES.DEFAULT_VALUE
    ).as("ATTRIBUTE_VALUE");

Map<String,String> attributes = 
    dsl.select(DICT_ATTRIBUTES.CODE, ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_FIELD)
        .from(DICT_ATTRIBUTES)
        .leftJoin(EXISTING_ATTRIBUTES)
        .on(DICT_ATTRIBUTES.ID
               .eq(EXISTING_ATTRIBUTES.field(ID_FIELD_NAME, Long.class))
           )
        .fetchMap(DICT_ATTRIBUTES.CODE, ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_FIELD);
```

In logs I found a little bit changed SQL query generated by JOOK:

```
SELECT D.CODE,
  NVL(S.VALUE, D.DEFAULT_VALUE) ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
FROM CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE_DICT D
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  (SELECT NULL ID, NULL VALUE FROM dual WHERE 1 = 0
  )
UNION ALL
  (SELECT CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE_DICT.ID,
    CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE.VALUE
   FROM CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE_DICT
   JOIN CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE
   ON CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE.ATTRIBUTE_ID = CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE_DICT.ID
   WHERE CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE.CLIENT_ID = 141
  )
 ) S ON D.ID = S.ID;
```

Any ideas how to improve my workaround are appreciated.